# First view in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I've got a very simple question, but unfortunately I don't know how to google it.

When my first page is loading I want to that angular shows me automatically first content in `<div ng-view>`, later is no problem for me because i use `$routeProvider` and when I make some route, content reload but how to do this when the page has loaded angular autmatically without any user's action shows the first view?

to better understanding what i mean this is code from my another application:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
 </head>
 <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ApplicationCtrl'>
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
   <div class='container'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
     <li><a href='/'>Posty</a></li>
     <li><a class='register' href='/register'>Rejestracja</a></li>
     <li><a class='login' href='/login'>Logowanie</a></li>
    </ul>    
    <p ng-if='currentUser' class='navbar-text navbar-right'>
     Zalogowany jako {{currentUser.username}}
    </p>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here is angular route code:

```js
angular.module('app')
.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
 });
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {controller:'PostsCtrl', templateUrl: 'posts.html'})
 .when('/register', {controller: 'RegisterCtrl', templateUrl: 'register.html'})
 .when('/login', {controller: 'LoginCtrl', templateUrl: 'login.html'});
});
```

so in that application the div was empty firstly and when i route to proper route like /login for example some context shows, what i want to do now is that div has some firstly content which is changing during user`s actions

Comment: what do you mean by "first content in ng-view ?

Comment: Uploading code will help us help you, too.

Comment: sorry by first content i mean dashboard and then in the same div content should change according to what user is clicking on navi bar for example his/her profile

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i dont have that code yet, just dont know how to start :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `run()` to execute code on application startup, such as triggering a registered route to activate on application startup.

`run()` is executed after `config()` where most likely the routes using `angular-route` have been defined.

Here is an example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/contact", {
        templateUrl : "contact.html"
    });
});

app.run(function($location) {
  // load /contact path on startup
  $location.path('/contact');
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Route "/contact" is activated on startup due to the statement within `app.run()` using the `$location` service's `path()` method.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pVu4aJJBEgh6gTd7kuyL?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yes this is it what i was looking for thank you very much and sorry that i edited my post so many time, but I'm still learning using stackoverflow.